# Error executing Maven jar file containing SparkSession builder

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, jar

I'm currently working on a project which includes Spark API for Scala, MongoDB and Maven.

The versions we're using are the following :

Spark : 2.2.0

Scala : 2.11.8

Maven : 3.5.3

MongoDB : 3.6.3

MongoDB connector for Spark : 2.2.0

The jar's main class contains this following line of code :

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
```

Here's my error when I try to run my main :

> Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
>       18/05/30 10:04:26 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.2.0
>       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.cache.
>       CacheBuilder.refreshAfterWrite(JLjava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;)Lcom/google/comm
>       on/cache/CacheBuilder;
>               at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.(Groups.java:96)
>               at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.(Groups.java:73)
>               at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Group
>       s.java:293)
>               at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupI
>       nformation.java:283)
>               at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(Use
>       rGroupInformation.java:260)
>               at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(
>       UserGroupInformation.java:789)
>               at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGrou
>       pInformation.java:774)
>               at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGr
>       oupInformation.java:647)
>               at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils
>       .scala:2430)
>               at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils
>       .scala:2430)
>               at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>               at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2430)
>               at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.(SparkContext.scala:295)
>               at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2509)
>               at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSessi
>       on.scala:909)
>               at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSessi
>       on.scala:901)
>               at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>               at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.sc
>       ala:901)
>               at fr.atos.gsec.Main$.main(Main.scala:12)
>               at fr.atos.gsec.Main.main(Main.scala)`

The error is triggered by the `getOrCreate()` method.

When I run this main directly on IntelliJ, it works and launches Spark without any problem.

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the libraries into the exported jar. By default, they are not included in the exported Jar as the IDE assumes they are present at runtime, which they are not. Otherwise, It could be that `your classpath contains two or more versions of guava.` Make sure you have just one `guava binary available` to the application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I included the dependencies in the jar with the maven assembly plugin. I tried to exclude guava from the spark-core dependency in the pom.xml but it's still not working.

Comment: Can you print dependency tree? With the help of tree, you will be able to know that how many times the dependency of guava is coming.

Comment: I printed the dependency tree and the guava dependency is coming twice : org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.22.2:compile and org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guava:jar:0.9.9:compile, even though I put exclusions in the corresponding dependencies in the pom..

Comment: Than you have to check once and exclude the dependency properly from there not from spark-core. It had worked for me and I hope after that you will be able to run your application.

Comment: We finally succeeded thanks to your help. Thanks a lot !